# Find systems of linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: A metal plate whose temperature at the point (x,y) is given $T(x,y)=200-5x^2-3xy-y^2$. Given a function $f(x,y)$, the vector $\nabla f= <f_x,f_y>$ points in the direction of greatest increase for f.

Problem 1: Compute $\nabla T(x,y)$.

> Question 1: $∇T(x,y)=<-10x-3y,-3x-2y>$. Is it right?

Problem 2: Denote the position at time t by $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ We want $r'(t)=\nabla T(r(t))$ for all t to ensure the temperature is increasing as much as possible. Interpret this equation as a system of linear ODEs with the form $r'=Ar$

> Question 2: not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your gradient calculation is not correct. Do the partial derivatives separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) yes (ii) $$\begin{bmatrix}\dot x\\\dot y\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-10&-3\\-3&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end {bmatrix}$$